# sqlite in syntax, by column

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, outer-join

when sqlite in syntax by column name.

a table.

```
_id   seq(text)   name(text)
 1     2            jone
 2     3            nike
 3     4            sara
```

b table.

```
_id   seqs(text)
 1    1,2,3,4 << comma text
```

here is sql.

```
select group_concat(name) from a where seq in (select seqs from b where _id = '1')
```

or

```
select group_concat(name) from a as t1 left join 
(select seqs from b where _id = '1') t2 on t1.seq in (t2.seqs)
```

i expect result below. (!!!  I WANT RESULT  !!!)

```
result
jone,nike,sara
```

but,

```
query result
(blank)
```

Why do not results I want?

What can I do to get the results you want me?

```
ex) jone,nike,sara
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot search comma delimited strings using `in` (well, if you used dynamic SQL).  You can do it using `like`:

```
select group_concat(name)
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b._id = 1 and ',' || b.seqs || ',' like '%,' || a.seq || ',%')
```

However, you shouldn't be storing lists of things in strings.  SQL has this great data structure of storing lists -- in fact, the whole language is built around it.  It is called a table.  You should be using a junction table that has one row per value, rather than stuffing integer values into strings.